# Trying to make a gradient border WITHOUT using a background div gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to make a border that has a gradient. Here's the catch - the border is not at the very edge of the div, so I can't use the old put-a-div-inside-a-div-and-make-the-background-div's-background-gradient trick. THe gradient nalso has to be repeating. I've already used a child div to create the effect of the border being inside the parent div, but now I need to make it gradient, too. For an example, I'm actually trying to make it exactly like the borders around the divs at the bottom of this page: [waysidefinehomes.com](http://www.waysidefinehomes.com/). The ones on here are just background images so I can't use them, I need this site to be responsive. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can everyone also stop downvoting me, if you can't answer the question just don't answer it. Not everyone is a pro, just trying to get some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the background with a radial gradient.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: radial-gradient(at 30% 20%, #ededed, #d6d1c7);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet quam massa. Aliquam et felis tempor, auctor lectus id, mattis quam. Ut ante libero, porta et ante nec, porttitor mattis sapien. Vestibulum porta bibendum lorem quis tristique. Pellentesque
  vestibulum, enim sed malesuada facilisis, lacus magna faucibus justo, sit amet venenatis metus metus sed purus. Sed vehicula mi et eleifend lacinia. Nunc eu auctor sem. Morbi vel pellentesque nibh. Aliquam convallis malesuada elit, in tincidunt sapien
  congue vitae. Etiam maximus eget neque eu dignissim. Aenean ut turpis at metus ullamcorper vehicula a non enim. Nullam tristique placerat odio vel molestie. Fusce commodo, sem vel aliquam tempus, est nibh consectetur nisi, et congue lorem arcu eu nibh.
  Morbi placerat malesuada urna posuere cursus. Nullam risus urna, mollis sit amet urna id, convallis pellentesque ligula.</div>
```

The next step would be adding a div inside for that slight 1px border that goes round the text.

```css
div.outside {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: radial-gradient(at 30% 20%, #ededed, #d6d1c7);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div .inside {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sit amet quam massa. Aliquam et felis tempor, auctor lectus id, mattis quam. Ut ante libero, porta et ante nec, porttitor mattis sapien. Vestibulum porta bibendum lorem quis tristique. Pellentesque
    vestibulum, enim sed malesuada facilisis, lacus magna faucibus justo, sit amet venenatis metus metus sed purus. Sed vehicula mi et eleifend lacinia. Nunc eu auctor sem. Morbi vel pellentesque nibh. Aliquam convallis malesuada elit, in tincidunt sapien
    congue vitae. Etiam maximus eget neque eu dignissim. Aenean ut turpis at metus ullamcorper vehicula a non enim. Nullam tristique placerat odio vel molestie. Fusce commodo, sem vel aliquam tempus, est nibh consectetur nisi, et congue lorem arcu eu
    nibh. Morbi placerat malesuada urna posuere cursus. Nullam risus urna, mollis sit amet urna id, convallis pellentesque ligula.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully

Comment: It should also by dynamic with height so responsive to a degree. You'll have to change the width to a percentage based value if you want it to be responsive with small screens.

Answer (score 1):

after looking at the site you linked to what about using a div with the wanted gradient then putting two more divs in that. One with a fat border and no fill then another with wide margins this should provide the see through gap wanted to the gradient behind.